# modify the following with function lambda and filter python2 code into python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, lambda, filter

I need to convert the following python2.7 code into python3.5, while getting errors

```
 for filename in sorted(glob.glob(self.path + '/test*.bmp'),
                               key=lambda f: int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), f))):

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ImageSegmentation/preprocess.py", line 53, in get_gland
    key=lambda f: int((filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), f)))):
  File "/Users/ImageSegmentation/preprocess.py", line 53, in <lambda>
    key=lambda f: int((filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), f)))):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'filter'
```

Comment: ...are you sure that worked in Python 2? Seems like it would get the same error, but with `'list'` instead of `'filter'`.

Comment: @glibdud no because filter used to return a string when passed a string. That was a nice feature, now gone...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, it's a string, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, when passed a string in input, `filter`  used to return a string, which was convenient.

Now `filter` returns a filter object, which needs to be iterated upon to get the results.

So you have to use `"".join()` on the result to force iteration & convert to string.

Also note that `lambda x: x.isdigit()` is overkill and underperformant, use `str.isdigit` directly.

Another potential bug in your code is that `f` is the full path name of the file, so if there are digits in the paths, they'll be taken into account (and would be difficult to figure out), so a proper fix would be:

```
int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, os.path.basename(f))))
```